# Proving an function is one-to-one, algebraically?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to show the following is one-to-one for all real numbers not equal to 0:

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{3x-1}{x}$

I think I could use some algebraic manipulation (showing that if $f(n) \neq f(m)\implies n \neq m$) to demonstrate this, but I'm now sure how to proceed:

$\frac{3x_1-1}{x_1}=\frac{3x_2-1}{x_2}$

$(3x_1-1)(x_2)=(3x_2-1)(x_1)$

Which is equivalent to...

$3x_1x_2-x_2=3x_2x_1-x_1$

From there I'm not sure how to progress, assuming I was on the right path to begin with. Is there a technique beyond just trial and error?

Comment: I fixed the parentheses.

Comment: The missing parentheses were the source of his error.

Comment: You should be able to finish now that your algebra error has been corrected. What you must do is show that $x_1=x_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the  function as $f(x)=3-\dfrac1x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Subtract $3x_1x_2$ from both sides. Also, you were originally missing some parentheses in your question.